# Looping through multiple databases

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2, c#-2.0

Our application uses multitenant model by implementing one database for each customer. The application is live now and is working fine and there are around 600 databases spread across two database servers. The databases are connected using a master database called admin which stores the details of all other databases. One of the requirement is to check the admin database and find all the databases, check specific tables in the databases and send email notifications. This is a backend process. Currently we use a windows service to do the same but we see that there are delays in sending the mails due to the looping of 600 databases. Is there any other way to handle this?

Thanks,
Anup